# Closure Compiler - best practice for JavaScript library projects?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, transpiler

I am trying to use Closure Compiler to minimize and validate my JavaScript library and I am struggling with one issue. I created a small project to highlight the problem. Here is the externs file with public API of my library. I defined it according to:

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/externs-and-exports

```js
/**
 * @fileoverview Public API of my-lib.js
 *
 * @externs
 */
const myLib = {};

myLib.foo = function() {};
```

And here is the implementation:

```js
// const myLib = {};

myLib.foo = function() {
  console.log("foo");
};
```

So the problem is that if I uncomment the first line, I am getting this error:

```
my-lib.js:1:6: ERROR - [JSC_REDECLARED_VARIABLE_ERROR] Illegal redeclared variable: myLib
  1| const myLib = {};
           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I don't, the output looks like this:

```js
(function(){myLib.foo=function(){console.log("foo")};})()
```

Which is good, because `myLib.foo` didn't get renamed so the externs are working, but in the same time the `myLib` namespace has not been created.

What would be the best practice for solving such an issue, or if there is none, maybe there is some workaround instead?

I pushed this example to github:

https://github.com/morisil/closure-compiler-lib-example

Answer (score 0):

Externs provide definitions for symbols that the compiler should consider to be already existing.

There are a couple of solutions:

```
/** @suppress {const,duplicate} */
const myLib = {}
```

or use a separate name internally and assign it in a way the compiler won't check:

```
globalThis['myLib'] = myInternalName;
```